# This keyword and it's usage

Tags: java

I understood the use of this keyword a lil bit but. I am  getting no output in my cmd when I run this program. It's like my show() method is not doing anything

```
class This_is

{

String city;

String name;

int roll;

This_is(String city,String name,int roll){

this.city=city;

this.name=name;

this.roll=roll;

} 

void show(){

System.out.println (this.city+""+this.name+""+this.roll); 

}

public Static void main(String args[]){

This_is I obj=new this_is ("rocky","rocky",12); 

obj.show();

}}
```

Comment: The output has no commas.

Comment: See the java spec on shadowing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1 especially the examples.

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't compile?

Comment: Can anyone explain it please

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the values in the same method, so you actually aren't printing `this.city` but the `city` parameter that has value "*rocky*"

`this.city` stay `null` and you can check it easily printing it:

```
System.out.println(this.city);
```

Or calling another method

```
public void printCity() {
    System.out.println(city); // Here is city is equivalent to this.city
}
```

In this second case you don't need to use `this.city` because there are no parameters named `city`

**Note:** I propose you to change some formatting and naming of your code.  Generally in java class names are camel format with upper first letter (`ThisIs` instead of `this_is`).

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere in `this_is`, `city` (without the `this`) refers to the parameter; this includes the assignment (which amounts to a no-op) and in the print statement.  Same thing for `name` and `roll`.  In fact, if you *removed* the instance variables, this will work exactly the same as it does now.

Comment: When I remove the instance variables it says cannot find symbol name,  city, roll